# How to import sortablejs properly with webpacker?

Tags: webpacker, sortablejs, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to import sortablejs by using webpacker gem in rails, but no luck so far.
With these settings I get error Sortable is not defined.

Imported it like this in javascript/packs/application.js

```
import 'sortablejs';
```

this is my config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  List: 'list.js',
  Sortable: 'sortablejs',
}))

module.exports = environment
```

I am aware of window.Sortable = Sortable; in application.js(works like that) but I am trying to avoid that, and expose Sortable somehow cleaner through webpacker if possible?
Any help/tips on how to debug and check what is wrong, or how to setup it correctly are most welcome.